# Drawing line in java

Tags: java, swing, awt

I have tried this code to draw a line and it works fine.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class New extends JFrame {
    public New() {
        setSize(960, 960);
        setVisible(true);
        setDefaultCloseOperation(EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(0, 480, 960, 480);
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        New n = new New();
    }
}
```

I also tried the below code to draw a line but no line shows up in the frame.

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test {
    public Test() {
        JFrame f = new JFrame("Test");
        f.setSize(960, 960);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }

    public void paint(Graphics g) {
        g.drawLine(0, 480, 960, 480);
    }

    public static void main(String []args) {
        Test t = new Test();
    }
}
```

I think there is no difference between these two snippets. Am I wrong? Is there some difference, and what is it?

Comment: `I have tried this code to draw a line and it works fine.` - No. That is NOT the way to do custom painting. Custom painting is done by overriding the `paintComponent()` method of a `JPanel` and then you add the panel to the frame. Read the section from the Swing tutorial on [Custom Painting](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/uiswing/painting/index.html) for more information and working examples.

Answer (score 2):

`JFrame` is declared in constructor which means that it will be deleted after `Test` was created. Also the `paint` method does not belong to `JFrame` but `Test`. So it won't be called.

Answer (score 1):

This because the method `paint(Graphics)` is never called in the second code snippet.

Indeed in the first code snippet, you make your class extends `JFrame` which is a sub class of `Container` that provides this method such that you override the method  `paint(Graphics)` which is called internally when the window is displayed.

In the second code snippet it is never called so your line is never displayed. You should create your own `JFrame` implementation in which you override the `paint` method then use it in the constructor of your class `Test`.

**NB:** `f` should not be a local variable in your constructor, it should be a field in your class `Test` to prevent bugs hard to find.

Answer (score 0):

On your 1st code your inheriting the `paint()` method from the `JFrame` class.

On your second code you're creating a method called `paint()` but it isn't [Window#paint()](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/awt/Window.html#paint(java.awt.Graphics)) but a new one.

If you want the same output then edit your code as follows:

```
import java.awt.*;
import javax.swing.*;

public class Test{
    private JFrame f;
    public Test(){
        f = new JFrame() {
            public void paint(Graphics g){
                g.drawLine(0,480,960,480);
            }
        };
        f.setSize(960,960);
        f.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);
        f.setVisible(true);
    }
    public static void main(String []args){
        Test t = new Test();
    }
}
```